# How to send Json in Post request with Web Api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have this method receiving a post request and i'm not able to send a json

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SalvarCliente")]
public HttpResponseMessage SalvarCliente(ClienteVM cliente)
{
    try
    {
        _clienteService.SalvarCliente(cliente);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = MessageJson("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso")
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

My class ClienteVM:

```
  public class ClienteVM
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string  Nome { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }

     public List<EnderecoVM> enderecos { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public byte Status { get; set; }

     }
```

which correct model of jason do i have to send? I'm testing by the postman
you don't need to put the List EnderecoVm for a while.

I Try:

[image]

Comment: What JSON have you tried using in your requests? And what's the exact behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @devNull i posted print with my json and results

Comment: Change Text to Json in your postman.

Answer (score 3):

Your postman should be like below:
[image]

Result:
[image]